# Score at Quiz app - Learning app

Tags: interface, feedback, audience, quiz

For a learning app, which is better: adding score or not?
The feedback will be after each question and at the end we will rank users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

I love learning apps, so I am happy to try and answer this. Since your questions is very general, I will give some general pointers. If these don't apply to you feel free to specify.

- Always answer this question first: **What is your goal?** Do you want to motivate people? Do you want people to concentrate? Do you want to encourage people to be persistent even it the face of frustrating process? Do want to encourage social competition? If so, why? All this will change the answer to your question.
- Adding a score generally falls under the umbrella of what is called **Gamification**. If you search for this term, you will find many reasons to use or not use it, from reports on overlap with gambling addiction to successful case studies like *DuoLingo*. I am sure you will find relevant inspiration from searching this term for a bit.
- This is an excellent question to answer with a **quantitative A/B test**! Create a version with the score and one without it, and get data - does the score make users more likely to come back to the app? Do they learn more? Are they on top of their leagues or on the bottom? Do a little survey on their emotional state or ask them to rate the experience, and so on. Since you are doing a learning app, you have lots of data anyways - use it!

I will end this with a general rule-of-thumb in UX: **Don't add features without having a good reason. If you don't have a compelling reason to *add* scoring, leave it out for the sake of simplicity.**